# Spark dynamic partitioning: SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException on read

Tags: apache-spark

### Question

*Is there any way to store data with different (not compatible) schemas in different partitions?*

### The issue

I use PySpark v2.4.5, parquet format and dynamic partitioning with the following hierachy: `BASE_PATH/COUNTRY=US/TYPE=sms/YEAR=2020/MONTH=04/DAY=10/`. Unfortunatelly it can't be changed.

I got `SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException`  on read. That happens because schema differs between different types (i.e. between sms and mms). Looks like Spark trying to merge to schemas on read under the hood.

If to be more precise, I can read data for `F.col('TYPE') == 'sms'`, because mms schema can be converted to sms. But when I'm filtering by `F.col('TYPE') == 'mms'`, than Spark fails.

### Code

```
# Works, because Spark doesn't try to merge schemas
spark_session \
   .read \
   .option('mergeSchema', False) \
   .parquet(BASE_PATH + '/COUNTRY_CODE=US/TYPE=mms/YEAR=2020/MONTH=04/DAY=07/HOUR=00') \
   .show()

# Doesn't work, because Spark trying to merge schemas for TYPE=sms and TYPE=mms. Mms data can't be converted to merged schema.
# Types are correct, from explain Spark treat date partitions as integers
# Predicate pushdown isn't used for some reason, there is no PushedFilter in explained plan
spark_session \
   .read \
   .option('mergeSchema', False) \
   .parquet(BASE_PATH) \
   .filter(F.col('COUNTRY') == 'US') \
   .filter(F.col('TYPE') == 'mms') \
   .filter(F.col('YEAR') == 2020) \
   .filter(F.col('MONTH') == 4) \
   .filter(F.col('DAY') == 10) \
   .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for situation it may be useful for someone. It's possible to have different data within different partitions. To make Spark no infer schema for parquet - specify the schema:

```
spark_session \
   .read \
   .schema(some_schema) \
   .option('mergeSchema', False) \
   .parquet(BASE_PATH) \
   .filter(F.col('COUNTRY') == 'US') \
   .filter(F.col('TYPE') == 'mms') \
   .filter(F.col('YEAR') == 2020) \
   .filter(F.col('MONTH') == 4) \
   .filter(F.col('DAY') == 10) \
   .show()
```